# Websphere MQ server configuration

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

somebody can help me in configuring Websphere MQ Server in WAS 8.5?I got the below error while creating the WAS MQ Server.

> Error: WebSphere MQ server MQSERVER connection test failed for WebSphere MQ queue    manager MQSERVER. CWSJP0050E: An attempt to connect to WebSphere MQ queue manager or queue sharing group MQSERVER failed. The WebSphere MQ reason code is Unknown (2538)..

Comment: I see error of you please share log file below as the configuring, maybe error generator in another log is first log run configuring, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

MQRC 2538 means "host not available". Check the host name and port name that you have specified and is pointing to the machine where MQ queue manager "MQSERVER" is running.

Check on which port your queue manager is listening. You can do that by using MQExplorer or runmqsc command shell on the machine where you queue manager is running. In a command prompt, run the following command

```
runmqsc MQSERVER
```

Once the runmqsc shell opens run the following command to list TCP listener.

```
dis listener(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LISTENER.TCP)
```

Check the PORT number displayed. By default it will be 0. You need to change this to some port number. To change the port number run the following command.

```
alter listner(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LISTENER.TCP) port(1414)
```

Once this is done you need to start the listener by running the following command

```
start listener(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LISTENER.TCP)
```

After this you can attempt your tests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Shashi, I didnt see any space for port number while creating the MQ server.Its my first MQ server configuration, could be please explain in detail.

Comment: Hi Shashi, I have been searching how and where to run these commands through putty.I hope MQExplorer may help but i would like to now how to run these commands with putty.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Logon using Putty to the Unix system where queue manager is running. After logging on you can run the runmqsc command. I am assuming your login profile has paths to MQ binaries included.

Comment: I didnt include anything binaries, could you please let me know how to do this activity.

Comment: There is a slight change for version 8.5 for alter commnad shown above which is as follows `ALTER LISTENER( SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LISTENER.TCP ) TRPTYPE (TCP) Port(1414)`